# Adding Event to HorizontalPanel (GWT)

Tags: java, gwt

I have to add an onLoad event handler to a Horizontal Panel.

I have tried adding addAttachHandler as it was specified in post [How do I setup for and/or handle onload event with GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575361/how-do-i-setup-for-and-or-handle-onload-event-with-gwt) but it doesn't work for me. Eclipse shows like there isn't any method such as addAttachHandler() available for HorizontalPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HorizontalPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HorizontalPanel.html) does have [addAttachHandler()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#addAttachHandler%28com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.AttachEvent.Handler%29) method, it's inherited from `Widget`.

Comment: Ya I too referred the docs. It is weird that it show error on using addAttachHandler() on HorizontalPanel. Is there any other way to do it. I think there are differences in versions. I couldn't see addAttachHandler() on Widget in the following doc http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html .Am not sure whether am correct.

Comment: if eclipse can't compile gwt code, don't you want to fix that, instead  of finding a workaround?

Comment: Am sure that my eclipse can compile gwt code. I had made other changes and those worked perfectly.

Comment: so how come then it says addAttachHandler doesn't exist on HorizontalPanel?

Comment: Am getting that redline in eclipse

Comment: GWT 1.5 (the doc you're linking to) is absolutely too old (more than 3 years old, an eternity for the Web!). `HasAttachHandlers` was added in GWT 2.1, which is already more than 1 year old. You should really upgrade, and always try to use the latest version of GWT.

Comment: @Thomas Broyer Am adding an additional functionality to the code already developed using GWT1.5. Is there any way to do it in the GWT1.5 as it is possible in GWT2.1

Comment: You'd have to extend `HorizontalPanel` to expose some event/hook (and override `onLoad` and `onUnload` to fire the event/call the callback). I believe it'd be easier to just upgrade to the latest GWT; there are chances it'd "just work" without changing anything to the code.