# Onload functionality for grid in GWT

Tags: gwt, grid

I am using GWT 2.4 and I have an EditorGridPanel in my page for which I want to have a onload functionality. Actually after grid is loaded with rows, I would like populate my form fields with first row values automatically. How can write a listner/handler to execute this logic in gwt.

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575361/how-do-i-setup-for-and-or-handle-onload-event-with-gwt).

Answer (score 0):

When your passing datastore values to grid.. try to get first record 
`store.getModels();` or `store.getAt(index)` or `getRecordAt(index)`

once you got record check not null and set values in form.

You can do this after gird loaded by set timer to some milliseconds delay. is this you need..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a handler for this. Typically, you would have an Activity or Presenter that drives these actions. When you receive your data from a server, you would do something like:

```
myView.populateMyGrid(ArrayList<MyObject> objects);
myView.populateMyPanelWithFirstRow();
```

Alternatively, you can add this to the method which populates your grid:

```
displayItems.addAll(objects);
populateMyPanelWithFirstRow(displayItems.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when I call loadGrid method on my grid to load rows, it is taking some time to load it (because data has to come from database, but  by that time the client code to populate form field with row data which is written after loadGrid method is getting executed and it ended up with not populating anything in my form field as the grid was empty by that time.

So, what I did was that I have added a listener(addStoreListener) to the store of my grid like below and written my logic inside the onLoad method, it worked perfectly.

```
 myGrid.getMyStore().addStoreListener(new StoreListenerAdapter() {
        public void onLoad(Store store, Record[] records) {
            ...
        }
    });
```